# How to step one week (7 days) in a for loop (datetime)

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a for loop like so:

```
for mydate in daterange (startDate, endDate):
```

this increments though each day. I want the step to be one week.
A hack would be to skip 6 days, but that is awful.
How to do this?

```
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)
```

Comment: Is `daterange(startDate, endDate)` a function?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why a hack to skip 6 days would be awful? Is it because the last period of the month will have invalid value and your desired preference for an overflow? Also give the reason like is it a mathematical way to sample data?

Comment: Just because it is 6 unnecessary loops. And yes, a step of 7 has to account for the 6 steps, but I would guess it is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a range-object with steps of 7 and add that to a start date:

```
import datetime

def daterange(startdate, enddate, steps=1): 
    """Yields dates in increments of steps days from startdate to enddate"""
    numdays = (enddate-startdate).days 
    for x in range (0, numdays, steps):
        yield startdate + datetime.timedelta(days = x)


today = datetime.datetime.today() 
end = today + datetime.timedelta(days=40)

print( list(daterange(today, end, 7)))
```

Output:

```
[datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 28, 19, 34, 26, 976681), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 5, 19, 34, 26, 976681), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 12, 19, 34, 26, 976681), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 19, 19, 34, 26, 976681), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 26, 19, 34, 26, 976681), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 2, 19, 34, 26, 976681)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add step size into your loop:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
     for n in range(0, int((end_date - start_date).days) + 1, 7):
         yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_dt = date(2018, 9, 1)
end_dt = date(2018, 10, 30)
for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Output:

```
2018-09-01
2018-09-08
2018-09-15
2018-09-22
2018-09-29
2018-10-06
2018-10-13
2018-10-20
2018-10-27
```

Comment: I see what you're doing here. I think, though, you have reversed the order of these two in the `for` statement: `end_date - start_date`

Comment: @AlLelopath fixed!